# jQuery's .live() ignoring events

Tags: javascript, jquery

Given the following snippet of HTML:

```
    Goggles <input type="checkbox" id="id_goggles_opt_in" name="goggles_opt_in">
    Approved <input type="checkbox" id="id_approved" name="approved">
```

and this JavaScript:

```
$('#id_approved').live('click', function() {
    alert('click is fine when selected by ID');
});

var $formInputs = $('.form input[type=text], .form input:file, .form textarea, .form select, .form input[type=checkbox]');

var $checkboxes = $formInputs.filter('[type=checkbox]');
console.log("This selector actually finds the elements: " + $checkboxes.size());
console.log($checkboxes)

$checkboxes.live('click', function() {
    alert('bizarrely this is never called');
});
```

The second alert is never fired. #jquery regulars advised me to just use `.delegate`, but why doesn't this work?

Example on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/amA3h/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mully is right -- using `.filter()` interferes with the `.live()` event.

This works:

```
var $checkboxes = $('.form input[type=checkbox]');
$checkboxes.live('click', function() {
    alert('bizarrely this is never called');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/amA3h/5/

Or, to do it `.delegate`-style:

```
$('.form').delegate('input:checkbox','click', function() {
    alert('bizarrely this is never called');
});
```

Comment: Caching is not a problem http://jsfiddle.net/amA3h/6/, at least not as i see it, look at this fiddle, rather the problem is as Mully pointed out, the live method should always be called after a selector.

Comment: Thanks. Looking at `delegate()`, it seems it's easier to avoid this pitfall because it takes the selector as an argument.

Answer (score 5):

From [jQuery's documentation](http://api.jquery.com/live/):

> DOM traversal methods are not supported for finding elements to send to .live(). Rather, the .live() method should always be called directly after a selector...